# How do you return a struct from an array within a function? (pointers)

Tags: c

Consider this code:

```
typedef struct fruits_s
{
    char* key;
    char value;
} fruits_t;

static fruits_t fruit_array[] = {
{ "Apple", 1 },
{ "Banana", 2 },
{ "Grape", 3 },
{ "Orange", 4 } };

static fruits_t* getFruitFromValue(char value)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(fruit_array)/sizeof(fruit_array[0]); i++){
        if (value == fruit_array[i].value){
            return fruit_array[i];
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to C and am still learning when pointers are necessary/used. I come spoiled from a Java background. So, in the above code, what I'm confused of is should the function return a *pointer* `fruits_t*`? Or something else? When I do `fruit_array[i]` is that a pointer to my struct, or the struct itself?

That being said, later in my code when I want to use the function, is it this:

```
 fruits_t* temp = getFruitFromValue(1);
```

or

```
 fruits_t temp = getFruitFromValue(1);
```

or

```
 fruits_t temp = &getFruitFromValue(1);
```

Comment: I think it will be return &fruit_array[i];

Comment: `fruit_array[i]` is the struct, if you want to return a pointer to it, `&fruit_array[i]` or, equivalently, `(fruit_array + i)`.

Comment: I guess that's part of my question... do I want to return a pointer to it, or not?

Comment: No need to declare your `getFruitFromValue()` as `static` when you to return a static array element.

Comment: @Deqing: the reason for declaring the function `static` may be so that it is not visible outside the source file; I would assume that was why.  I grant you there could be confusion about it, but it's not clear that there is confusion about it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that's actually why I did it, I assumed it was good practice to limit the scope as such.

Comment: It is good practice to limit scope; congratulations on doing so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function could return either — your choice.  You've said you'll return a pointer; that's OK as long as you do.

When you write:

```
static fruits_t *getFruitFromValue(char value)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(fruit_array)/sizeof(fruit_array[0]); i++){
        if (value == fruit_array[i].value){
            return fruit_array[i];
        }
    }
}
```

There are several problems:

1. `fruit_array[i]` is a structure, not a pointer.  Use `return &fruit_array[i];`.
2. If the loop exits, you don't return a value from the function at all.

Fixing those leads to:

```
static fruits_t *getFruitFromValue(char value)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(fruit_array)/sizeof(fruit_array[0]); i++)
    {
        if (value == fruit_array[i].value)
            return &fruit_array[i];
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

This is OK because the pointer you return is to static data that will outlive the function.  If you tried to return a pointer to non-static data, you would (probably) have a bug on your hands, unless you used dynamic memory allocation (via `malloc()` et al).

You could also return the structure; handling the error return becomes harder.  If you've got C99, you can use a 'compound literal':

```
static fruits_t getFruitFromValue(char value)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(fruit_array)/sizeof(fruit_array[0]); i++)
    {
        if (value == fruit_array[i].value)
            return fruit_array[i];
    }
    return (fruits_t){ .key = "", .value = 0 };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I understand most of your points. I guess what I'd like to know is, WHY would I return a pointer to this data vs the struct itself? Here as you said the struct outlives the function, so I know if it didn't a pointer to it would be a bad idea. But do you have any other thoughts?

Comment: For a small structure like this, it's reasonable to return a copy of the structure. If the structure was large (say hundreds of bytes or bigger), then returning a pointer is more sensible than returning the value. It's always important to ensure that a pointer points to live data; returning a value largely gets away from the issue (though even here, you have a `char *` within the structure; it's safe because of the way the structures are allocated, but it would not be hard to run into problems). You could use `struct fruits_s { char key[11]; char value; };` to avoid a pointer in the structure.

Comment: `For a small structure like this, it's reasonable to return a copy of the structure.`

So is a copy created and an implicit "malloc" performed, allocating memory to this copy? Like this uses more memory than returning a pointer, correct?

Comment: The mechanics are up to the compiler, but it won't usually use `malloc()` because it would then have to use `free()` at the right point in time too.  But when returning a value, yes, a copy is created, usually in stack space, and the calling function copies the value into the variable it is assigned to.  For most structures, yes, the copy uses more memory than a pointer, but the compiler minimizes the cost.  OTOH, the value saves having to ensure that the pointer is stable.  It depends on context, hence my opening comment: 'The function could return either [a pointer or a structure]'.